# changing css on click on checkbox with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, logic

Here I'm trying to change the css of appended item having class as '.item', on click into checkbox .
***What's happening over here is: when I'm clicking the added item the css('line-through') is applied; instead I want css to be applied when only I click checkbox.***

I tried running the individual queries via console and it returned correct value but its not displaying the write css.

```js
function entervalue()
{
  var text = $('#inputext').val();
      $("#list").append('<div class="item"> <input type="checkbox"> ' + text + '</div>');
  $("#inputext").val('');
}



$(document).ready(function(){

$('#inputext').keyup(function(b)
{

if (b.keyCode===13)
{
  entervalue();
}

})
});
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  if ($(this).css('textDecoration') == 'line-through')
  {
    $(this).css('textDecoration', 'none');
  }
  else

  {
      $(this).css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
  }

});
```

```css
body {
    font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue';
    line-height: 1.4em;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#inputext {
  background: white;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  position: fixed;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: floralwhite;
  width: 26%;
}


#app{
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 72%;
  height: 70%;
  border-bottom-style:inset;
  border-width: thick;
  border-radius: 3%;
  margin-left: 13%;
  margin-top: 19%;
}

#item1{
  font-weight: 500;
}
.item{
  font-size: 20px;
      border-bottom: solid darkcyan;
      margin-bottom: 5%;
      margin-top: 6%;
      margin-right: 3%;
      margin-left: -5%;

}
.maincontent{

  background-color: darkseagreen;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-left: 36%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 30%;
  position: fixed;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: thick;
  border-radius: 5%;

}
.strikeThrough{
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

```html
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="maincontent">

<input type="text" id="inputext" placeholder="todos"/>
<div id="app">
<ul id="list">

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

```
function entervalue()
{
  var text = $('#inputext').val();
      $("#list").append('<div class="item"> <input type="checkbox"> ' + text + '</div>');
  $("#inputext").val('');
}



$(document).ready(function(){

$('#inputext').keyup(function(b)
{

if (b.keyCode===13)
{
  entervalue();
}

})
});
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  if ($(this).css('textDecoration') == 'line-through')
  {
    $(this).css('textDecoration', 'none');
  }
  else

  {
      $(this).css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
  }

});
```

Comment: `textDecoration` should be `text-decoration` no?

Comment: It's `text-decoration` , [here you go.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the "appended item" comment in your post - are you adding content to the DOM after the page has loaded? in which case you will need to designate the click event handler ($(document).on('click','textCheckbox...' etc).

The following is a better alternative to altering the the css on a single element - you designate a class (with the CSS of the strike though)and then toggle it on the checkbox state.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#textCheckbox').on('click',function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked'))        {$('.item').addClass('strikeThrough')}
       else{$('.item').removeClass('strikeThrough')}
});
    })
```

```css
.strikeThrough{text-decoration:line-through}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Checkbox
  <input type="checkbox" id="textCheckbox">
</label>

<p class="item">TEST CONTENT</p>
```

you can even abbreviate this by using .toggleClass() as follows (simply toggles the line-through class on each click of the checkbox.:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#textCheckbox').on('click',function(){
       $('.item').toggleClass('strikeThrough')
});
    })
```

```css
.strikeThrough{text-decoration:line-through}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Checkbox
  <input type="checkbox" id="textCheckbox">
</label>

<p class="item">TEST CONTENT</p>
```

Comment: i tried making changes as suggested , but still query is same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onchange event handler on the checkbox and to check whether the checkbox is checked use `$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked')`

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
     console.log($('.item').css('textDecoration'));
  if ($('.item').css('textDecoration') == 'line-through')
  {
    $('.item').css('textDecoration', 'none');
  }
  else

  {
      $('.item').css('textecoration', 'line-through');
  }
  }
 

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<div class="item" >Hello World</div>
```

If you want the item having class `.item` to have css line-through when checkbox checked and not to when checkbox is unchecked. This is what you need

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
     
  
      $('.item').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
  }
  
  else {
      
     $('.item').css('text-decoration', 'none');
  }
 

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<div class="item" >Hello World</div>
```

Comment: i tried making changes as suggested , but still query is same.

Answer (score 0):

> may be this will help you

```js
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var that = this;
    $('.txt-class').css("background-color", function() {
        return that.checked ? "#ff0000" : "";
    });
  
   $('.txt-class').css("textDecoration", function() {
        return that.checked ? "line-through" : "";
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='1'>1</div>
<div class="txt-class">
Ganesh Putta
</div>
```

Comment: i tried making changes as suggested , but still query is same.

Comment: oh really...my code is working properly..then add your code to snippet, then i will change there

Comment: dude i asked you to copy your code to snippet, so that it is easy to solve

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $(this).parent().find('.item').css('text-decoration','line-through');
    }         
    else {
        $(this).parent().find('.item').css('text-decoration','none');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<div class="check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /><span class="item">Pick up Comic Books</span></div>
<div class="check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /><span class="item">Cook Dinner</span></div>
```

By putting the text and the checkbox inside the label tag, you can check the item by simply click on the text as well.

*Edit: Updates made as per OP's comment*

Comment: i tried making changes as suggested , but still query is same.

Comment: Could you explain more? What do you mean by _query is same_ ? Does it not strike through but gets checked? does it strike through?

Comment: The css is applied but i want css to be applied only if I check the checkbox, right now if I click on the input text also the css gets applied

Comment: @GauravSoni I've updated the answer. Try now. The CSS changes only when the checkbox is clicked and not the task text.

Answer (score 0):

try below. **NOTE : in your case textDecoration should be text-decoration**

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">



</style>

<body>

<input type="checkbox"> Pick me
 <p>I'm under him</p>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change',function(){
    var is_it_checked = $(this).prop("checked");//check the checkbox is checked or not

    //according to the condition, do the styles with if condition like below
    if (is_it_checked == true) 
      {
        $("p").css({"text-decoration":"line-through"});
      }
     else
     {
       $("p").css({"text-decoration":"none"});
     }


  });
});

</script>

</html>
```